# Is there a way to make my iPhone appear as as either an OSX/linux/windows device to a WiFi network?

Tags: windows, linux, wifi, vpn, iphone

My school prevents iOS devices from gaining access to the internet. I am able to connect to the WiFi but after I am redirected to the terms of service page and click "accept" it redirects me a page that says "your operating system is not supported" and won't allow me to connect to any websites. VPN? User agent masker/blocker? I am looking for a solution that is completely untraceable so I can not be caught, however if you have any ideas please let me know. Thank you!

Comment: Your school prevents iOS but allows Android? If so, tbh, that seems like valid grounds for a discussion with the administration about a policy change.

Answer (score 3):

The most commonly used method I've seen captive portals use to determine a device's operating system is to check a browser's [`User-Agent` HTTP header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent).

Since you are using an iPhone, you could use a browser that allows user agent switching. A list of iOS browsers with that capability can be found [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/40647/is-there-a-web-browser-for-ios-that-will-allow-me-to-change-the-user-agent).

Another method would be to use an authorized device to gain internet access and spoofing your iPhone's MAC address to match that of the authorized device. However, I do not believe this is possible on the iPhone without a jailbreak.